# Ionic 2 opening external browser after reloading the app

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 app, I am able to open links in the external browser (mobile safari on iOS) by calling

```
window.open(myURL, "_system");
```

however, I would like to be able to reset the entire app without quitting and relaunching it, and the simplest way appears to be to just call `window.location.reload();`

This works, but causes calls to `window.open` to open the link in the ionic web view, breaking the app.

Is there an alternate way to reload the app without breaking `window.open`?